# Can not run signalR client on Python

Tags: python, pip, signalr

I am running some Python code on Raspberry Pi and now I need real time communication. I have a SignalR hub hosted on Azure and in order to connect to it I am using [this](https://pypi.org/project/signalr-client/) python client. Since I am quite new to python I have some lame questions:

1. After I did `pip install signalr-client` I tried `pip install -r requirements` but then nothing happens. I just get an error `Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements'` As I understood this is some kind of a file which contains some references but not really sure how it is supposed to execute.
2. After the failure with installing `pip install -r requirements` I decided to try it directly as it is right now and I copied the code from the sample (modified with the metadata for my hub). Once I try to run it I get an error on the second line `from signalr import Connection` saying that there's no such module as **signalr**. Do you have any idea what could be this and is there any chance for those two to be related?

**NOTE:** When I execute `pydoc modules` I can see it there in the list.

Also, regarding python and pip versions I get:

- python -V : Python 2.7.13
- pip -V : pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: I guess the line with installing requirements refers to `signalR` project development, you shouldn't need that. The description in the docs is somehow vague at that point. If you clone the [project source code repository](https://github.com/TargetProcess/signalr-client-py), you'll find the file `requirements` there and will be able to install from it. It contains some additional packages required to build the wheel file and upload it to PyPI.

Comment: What I did after your comment was to create such file in my directory and copy/paste the content of the repo file. Now it did find the file and extracted everything which was described in it but STILL I get the error from my second question "signalr - > no such module "

Comment: Your `pip` command probably refers to wrong Python version. Do `python -V` and `pip -V` and post them here.

Comment: I just updated my question with the versions. Btw, do you think the order of requirements and signalr-client installation matters?

Comment: No, those are unrelated. I still think that somewhere a wrong Python version somes to play - maybe it's a wrong shebang line in the script where the import fails? Cause I can't reproduce it on my machine: `pip install signalr-client && python -c "from signalr import Connection"` works, so there's nothing wrong with the package itself.

Comment: I have also other files in that folder. I tried to create completely new one and did the installations there but still the same. I get an error that signalr module is missing.

Comment: Does `python -c "from signalr import Connection"` work from command line?

Comment: If I do it like this in the command line it works. There's no error.

Comment: Then it must be the script. If you run `python my_failing_script.py`, does it throw the error?

Comment: Quite interesting. If I do 'sudo python failing_script.py' it says signalr module is missing if I do it without the 'sudo' it throws another error which is not related to the module import but rather to another peace of code inside of the file.

Comment: Try running `sudo -E python script.py`; if this works, you get a different environment when running `sudo`, probably the `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` env vars differ.

Comment: It seems to work with this one also.

Comment: Then I'd say that's not a problem with `pip` or `python`, but rather with your environment - run `env`, then `sudo env` and check what's different. Most probably it's `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` set in your `.bashrc`. Or look up the `sudo` configuration that retains the local enviroment.